Remove query parameters when following link in Ionic React
In my ionic react project I have a tab bar with several links, however when I use href="/page" on the IonTabBarButton Component, it maintains the query parameters if the link already has them. (eg www.example.com/page1?foo=bar goes to www.example.com/page2?foo=bar when href='page2'. I have tried resetting the query parameters using onClick={() => {window.location.search = ''}} but it still leaves a question mark which is not user friendly. I also tried using () => history.push("/page") but it isn't working because when I use history = useHistory(); history is undefined. Here is the current error for the following code.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

I have also tried to fix this problem by using withRouter(App) when exporting it, wrapping my whole <App> in main.tsx with a <Route>, <IonRouter> etc but none of those solutions work.
Here is a minimal repro based off the default tabs project by the ionic react team.
import { Redirect, Route, Switch, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  IonApp,
  IonIcon,
  IonLabel,
  IonRouterOutlet,
  IonTabBar,
  IonTabButton,
  IonTabs,
  setupIonicReact
} from '@ionic/react';
import { IonReactRouter } from '@ionic/react-router';
import { ellipse, square, triangle } from 'ionicons/icons';
import Tab1 from './pages/Tab1';
import Tab2 from './pages/Tab2';
import Tab3 from './pages/Tab3';

/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
import '@ionic/react/css/core.css';

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
import '@ionic/react/css/normalize.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/structure.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/typography.css';

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
import '@ionic/react/css/padding.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/float-elements.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-alignment.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-transformation.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/flex-utils.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/display.css';

/* Theme variables */
import './theme/variables.css';

setupIonicReact();

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  
  return (
    <IonApp>
      <IonReactRouter>
        <IonTabs>
          <IonRouterOutlet>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/tab1">
                <Tab1 />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/tab2">
                <Tab2 />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/tab3">
                <Tab3 />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/">
                <Redirect to="/tab1" />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </IonRouterOutlet>
          <IonTabBar slot="bottom">
            <IonTabButton tab="tab1" onClick={() => history.push("/tab1")}>
              <IonIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={triangle} />
              <IonLabel>Tab 1</IonLabel>
            </IonTabButton>
            <IonTabButton tab="tab2" onClick={() => history.push("/tab2")}>
              <IonIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={ellipse} />
              <IonLabel>Tab 2</IonLabel>
            </IonTabButton>
            <IonTabButton tab="tab3" onClick={() => history.push("/tab3")}>
              <IonIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={square} />
              <IonLabel>Tab 3</IonLabel>
            </IonTabButton>
          </IonTabBar>
        </IonTabs>
      </IonReactRouter>
    </IonApp>
  );
};

export default App;


